# Detect hidden unknown patterns when visualization fails

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pattern-recognition

I have a fast set of multi dimensional timebased data which i suspect contain patterns. I simplified the dataset to create a custom visualization.

Humans see patterns in the visualization but the result of the pattern cannot be explained by the visualization. This is because of the simplification step, it hides data which is important.

I cannot put all my data in my visualization cause than humans cannot see the possible patterns anymore because too much data and dimensions are visualized.

Is there a technique that can detect hidden unknown patterns in a data set? (without using visualization, and without me learning the technique patterns) .

One optional extra would be that the technique should somehow be able to "explain the patterns" to me so that i can check if they make sense.

[edit] i can give the technique a collection of small sized datasets (extracted from the big dataset; still very multi dimensional) that i know that contain patterns (by using my visualization). The technique then needs to analyze under what conditions a pattern produces result a or result b.

Answer (score 1):

First of, how did you "simplify" the data? If you did it without any heuristics, you might go ahead and perform [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis). The very idea of PCA is to solve your problem: Not losing "important" data while having a dimensional reduction. You can visualize your principal components so that patterns can be detected by the human eye as well as algorithms.

To your 2nd question: Yes, there are techniques that can detect hidden unknown patterns in data. However, this is a huge field  (Machine Learning) and what algorithm you'd use, would depend on your problem structure, so it's impossible to give a specific model name at this point. From what you specified, neural networks in general seem fit to do the job. After you trained a network, you can visualize the activations or weights (Hinton Diagram) to perform an analysis on which input data is treated "similarly".